# Как осуществить передачу видео из камеры android на сервер посредством websocket?

Tags: java, android, websocket, socket.io

Дано: android-клиент, nodejs-server (express, socket.io), браузер.
Нужно осуществить потоковую передачу видео через WS из android-приложения на сервер, далее сервер будет транслировать данные нужному клиенту в браузер, и там видео будет рендериться посредством js/html.

В данный момент меня интересует 1й этап, как транслировать видео из камеры android на сервер через WS? Подойдет ли для этого [socket.io-client-java](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java)?

Возможно вы знаете или считаете более правильно использовать не веб-сокет, а другую технологию, буду благодарен если напишете свой вариант решения задачи (но сервер должен быть на реализован node.js)

Comment: Почему именно WS? Он же не очень предназначен для этого

Comment: @andreymal возможно, буду благодарен если напишете свой вариант решения задачи (но сервер должен быть именно node)

Comment: Вообще для подобных вещей делали WebRTC, но лично я с ним не работал и решения задачи не напишу) А ещё, если вы пишете android-приложение, то дополнительно непонятно, почему выбор пал на WS, а не самые обкновенные TCP-сокеты, это ж не браузер с ограничениями

Comment: @andreymal потому что веб-сервис уже написан, и использует эти технологии, сейчас задача - написать android-клиент

Comment: Если уже и получение видео сделано по вебсокетам, то тогда ладно

Comment: @andreymal а есть пример реализации с использованием TCP-сокетов, android и node.js? Интересно бы взглянуть на толковый пример. Я в данный момент на этапе ознакамления

Comment: Я не android-разработчик и по существу ответить не могу. Просто доношу до вашего сведения, что WS не единственный возможный способ передачи видео :) Если вы допускаете использование не WS, это поможет получить конструктивный ответ от тех пользователей, кто android-разработчиком всё-таки является)

Comment: Есть приложение ip cam или что-то типа этого, если что можно залезть посмотреть как оно работает